# When to use xargs when piping?

Tags: bash, xargs

I am new to bash and I am trying to understand the use of `xargs`, which is still not clear for me. For example:

```
history | grep ls
```

Here I am searching for the command `ls` in my history. In this command, I did not use `xargs` and it worked fine.

```
find /etc - name "*.txt" | xargs ls -l
```

I this one, I had to use `xargs` but I still can not understand the difference and I am not able to decide correctly when to use `xargs` and when not.

Comment: The bottom line is there is a limit to the size of the command line commands can take. (it is a hardcoded number usually `128KiB`) see [**What defines the maximum size for a command single argument?**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120642/what-defines-the-maximum-size-for-a-command-single-argument). When your command line exceeds that size, your alternative is to use `xargs` which will break that up and process the command for you.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`xargs` can be used when you need to take the output from one command and use it as *an argument* to another. A pipe alone takes the output from one command and sends it to the *input stream* of another.

So in your first example, `grep` can accept data from standard input, rather than as an argument and `xargs` is not needed.

`xargs` takes data from standard input and executes a command. By default, the data is appended to the end of the command as an argument. It can be inserted anywhere however, using a placeholder for the input. The traditional placeholder is `{}`; using that, your second command might then be written as:

```
find /etc -name "*.txt" | xargs -I {} ls -l {}
```

If you have 3 text files in `/etc` you'll get a full directory listing of each. Of course, you could just have easily written `ls -l /etc/*.txt` and saved the trouble.

Another example lets you rename those files, and shows when the placeholder would be required. `{}` has to be used twice to specify the source and destination names.

```
find /etc -name "*.txt" | xargs -I {} mv {} {}.bak
```

These are both bad examples, and will break as soon as you have a filename containing whitespace. You can work around that by telling `find` to separate filenames with a null character.

```
find /etc -print0 -name "*.txt" | xargs -I {} -0 mv {} {}.bak
```

My personal opinion is that there are almost always alternatives to using `xargs` (such as the `-exec` argument to `find`, or the [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) operator) and you will be better served by learning those.

Comment: In case you find it useful, I use this: https://gitlab.com/es20490446e/args

Comment: can you explain what `-I {}` is in `xargs -I {}`?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal did you read the second paragraph of the answer? It specifies the placeholder.

Answer (score 20):

When you use piping without `xargs`, the actual data is fed into the next command. On the other hand, when using piping with `xargs`, the actual data is viewed as a parameter to the next command. To give a concrete example, say you have a folder with `a.txt` and `b.txt`. `a.txt` contains just a single line '*hello world!*', and `b.txt` is just empty.

If you do

```
ls | grep txt
```

you would end up getting the output:

```
a.txt
b.txt
```

Yet, if you do

```
ls | xargs grep txt
```

you would get nothing since neither file a.txt nor b.txt contains the word *txt*.

If the command is

```
ls | xargs grep hello
```

you would get:

```
hello world!
```

That's because with `xargs`, the two filenames given by `ls` are passed to `grep` as arguments, rather than the actual content.

Comment: In `ls | grep txt`, `grep` still gets a filename (something like "/proc/1551/fd/0") as its argument, and then grep search in that file.

Answer (score 5):

#### Understanding the data flow

While the pipe operator `|` redirects the *stdout* from the last command to the *stdin* of the next command, the `xargs` command builds and executes a command from the *stdin*.

To put it simply:

- `|`  stdout -> **stdin**
- `xargs` stdin -> **command arguments**

As xargs happens to expect the result of the pipe operator, a combination of both comes of in handy for converting stdout into command arguments:

- `| xargs` stdout -> stdin (pipe) -> **command arguments** (xargs)

#### When to use `|` and `| xargs`?

To put it simply, **it depends on the command you want to execute**, as different commands handle the *stdin* or *command arguments* in different ways, depending on it's implementation.

In other words, even commands which accept both stdin and arguments can behaviour differently depending on which one of them you provided, as you can see in the examples bellow.

**Still, if you want some kind of rule, you can think that:**

- if the data you want a command to process is already in the *stdout*, you should use the pipe operator `|`;
- if the stdout contains either names of files whose content you want to process or even arguments for changing a command's default behaviour, you should use the combination `| xargs`;

However, be prepared for exceptions.

---

#### Examples

Setting up the scenario for the next examples:

```
echo "hello_world_content" > "hello_world.txt"
# Creates a file named "hello_world.txt" and
# writes "hello_world_content" inside it
```

The `grep` command:

```
ls | grep "hello"
# Grep searches for 'hello' in the stdout of the ls command
# Outputs: hello_world.txt


ls | xargs grep "hello"
# Corresponds to: grep 'hello_world.txt'
# Outputs: hello_world_content
```

The `echo` command:

```
ls | echo
# Outputs a blank line, as echo seems to ignore the stdin
# Outputs:


ls | xargs echo
# Corresponds to: echo 'hello_world.txt'
# Outputs: hello_world.txt
```

The `cat` command:

```
ls | cat
# Reads and prints the stdout of ls
# Outputs: hello_world.txt


ls | xargs cat
# Corresponds to: cat 'hello_world.txt'
# Outputs: hello_world_content
```

The `cat` command [Part II]:

```
echo "this_file_does_not_exists.txt" | cat
# Reads and prints the stdout of echo
# Outputs: this_file_does_not_exists.txt


echo "this_file_does_not_exists.txt" | xargs cat
# Corresponds to: cat 'this_file_does_not_exists.txt'
# Outputs error: cat: this_file_does_not_exists.txt: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Avoid `xargs` for now. Return to `xargs` when you have written dozens or hundreds of scripts.

Commands can get their input from parameters (like `rm bad_example`) or can get the input from `stdin` (not just the y on the question after `rm -i is_this_bad_too`, but also `read answer`). Other commands like `grep` and `sed` will look for parameters and when the parameters don't show the input, switch to the input.
Your `grep` example works fine reading from stdin, nothing special needed.
Your `ls` needs the output of find as a parameter. `xargs` is just one way to  turn things around. Use `man xargs` for more about xargs. Alternatives:

```
find /etc -name "*.txt" -exec ls -l {} \;
find /etc -name "*.txt" -ls
ls -l $(find /etc -name "*.txt" )
ls /etc/*.txt
```

First try to see which of this commands is best when you have `a nasty filename with spaces.txt` in /etc.

Answer (score 2):

xargs(1) is dangerous (broken, exploitable, etc.) when **reading non-NUL-delimited input**.

If you're working with filenames, use `find`'s -exec [command] {} + instead.
If you can get NUL-delimited output, use `xargs -0`.

Comment: @SaraHamad : you may be able to get null terminated strings from your find by adding `-print0` to your cmd-line. Check you man page. (most new versions have it)

Comment: Wouldn't that read better be IFS= read -r -d '' line to ensure reading null separated input?

Comment: @DirkHerrmann You're correct. Though I wrote it for the general case. I removed this part according to your comment.

Comment: Being "dangerous (broken, exploitable, etc.)" doesn't mean that it is not super useful for one-shot scripts to grind dozens of files :)

Comment: @JakubM. Grrrrind to **dust!**

Comment: This might be true, but won't help OP with is question one bit!

Comment: @CarlosTeixeira I disagree, but thank you for sharing your opinion with the public :)

Answer (score 1):

GNU Parallel can do the same as xargs, but does not have the broken and exploitable "features".

You can learn GNU Parallel by looking at examples http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Working-as-xargs--n1.-Argument-appending and walking through the tutorial http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html