# Bash Script is not working

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

When i am writing the script like this

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                       

pidof MX-CM48 | xargs kill                                                      

if [ -f /home/root/MX-CM48NEW ]; then                                           
    mv /home/root/MX-CM48NEW /home/root/MX-CM48                                 
    chmod 777 /home/root/MX-CM48                                                
fi                                                                              

cd /home/root                                                                   
./MX-CM48 &
```

**the script is working.**

but when i am trying to write it like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
NEW_FILE="/home/root/MX-CM48NEW"
OLD_FILE="/home/root/MX-CM48"
PATH="/home/root"
APP_NAME="MX-CM48"

pidof $APP_NAME | xargs kill

if [ -f $NEW_FILE ]; then
    mv $NEW_FILE $OLD_FILE
    chmod 777 $OLD_FILE
fi

cd $PATH
./$APP_NAME &
```

the pidof and the if are not working.

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](https://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use xargs when piping?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35589179/608639), [How to set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4651437/608639)

Comment: Find out what the PATH variable means and why it makes sense to use lowercase letters for your own variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you copied all commands to `/home/root`, it is pretty clear what is wrong.

```
PATH="/home/root"
```

should (probably) be:

```
PATH="$PATH:/home/root"
```

or use full path-names, like in:

```
/usr/bin/pidof $APP_NAME | /usr/bin/xargs /bin/kill
```

Comment: This is *not* the right answer -- the `$PATH` variable has a special meaning, and you should never try to use it for something else.

Comment: I assumed, that there are some executable in `/home/root` that are called from the script and that, therefore, it had to be appended to the existing PATH; therefore the "probably". I agree that your explanation is more elaborate and perhaps therefore more helpfull for understanding the meaning of PATH.

Answer (score 4):

The `PATH` environment variable defines where the system looks for the executables corresponding to commands. It's a colon-delimited list of directories that contain executable files, something like `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. So when you use a command like `mv`, the system looks for a file named "mv" in /usr/local/bin, then in /usr/bin, then in /bin etc.

When you set `PATH` to "/home/root" in the script, that then becomes the only place the system will look for command executables. I presume that's not what you wanted at all.

The solution is simple: use a different name for your variable. Actually, it's best to use lower- or mixed-case variable names for your things, because there are a lot of all-caps variable names that have some sort of special meaning and it's hard to remember & avoid all of them.

BTW, you should (almost) always double-quote variable references, e.g. `pidof "$APP_NAME"` to avoid unexpected weirdness from the way the shell parses unquoted variables. Finally, when you use `cd` in a script, you should always check for an error; otherwise if the `cd` command fails, the rest of the script will blindly continue executing in the wrong place.

```
cd "$path" || {
    echo "Error moving to $path directory; giving up" >&2
    exit 1
}
"./$app_name" &
```